# Troubles when trying to play a DVD

Tags: 11.10, dvd, multimedia, video-player

I'm trying to play a DVD I recently bought, but when I try to, sometimes a message appears:

*Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed.*

However I've cheked the ubuntu documentation and installed the libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 gstreamerx.xx-plugins-ugly and bad.

Comment: Have u tried VLC? it works for me so well! :) or check the `ubuntu restricted extra` packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Playing Encrypted DVDs**

To play encrypted DVDs, the libdvdcss2 package is essential. libdvdcss is a simple library designed for accessing DVDs like a block device without having to bother about the decryption.

Below are the instructions for installing the packages using the command line.

**With the entire Medibuntu repository**

**Adding the repository**

The following bash command adds Medibuntu's repository to Ubuntu. It also adds Medibuntu's GPG key to your keyring, which is needed to authenticate the Medibuntu packages.

This command should be run in the Terminal :

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

If you have added the entire Medibuntu repository, you just need to install the package using APT:

sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2

**With individual packages**

If you wish to install just libdvdcss2, you can first download the individual package and then install the package.

```
i386:

wget -c http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_i386.deb

amd64:

wget -c http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Source [How to add a mediubuntu repository](http://medibuntu.org/repository.php)

Comment: I tried this but to no avail! :(