# Could not read dvd despite having restricted extras

Tags: dvd, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I still can't seem to play movie DVDs on my Ubuntu 11.10 even after installing restricted extras and after trying [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/70010/41821)

This[a] is the error message that I get with movie player.
VLC doesn't play the DVD either.

What gives

[a]`Could not read DVD. This may be because the DVD is encrypted and a DVD decryption library is not installed.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the Terminal under Applications > Accessories > Terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly

sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

---

Reference:

- http://joesteiger.com/2011/03/26/watch-dvds-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Strangely it worked this time around. I guess I might have been somehow missing something previously. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as well. The first command did nothing (I already had all the packages) but the second command got things going. Was on Xubuntu 13.04 with Extra Restricted installed.

Answer (score 5):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

This link is a well written response the these kind of problems, including troubleshooting. Well worth a read
Let us know if it helps
Good Luck - Mal

Answer (score 2):

From: http:// ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10711874

Originally Posted by uRock View Post
https:// help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu You need to install packages for decrypting the movies.

32bit

```
wget -c http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_i386.deb
```

64bit

```
wget -c http://packages.medibuntu.org/pool/free/libd/libdvdcss/libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdvdcss2_1.2.9-2medibuntu4_amd64.deb
```

WIN.

Answer (score 0):

QUICKTIME. I stumbled to this post after searching the net for weeks. I tried everything, including "regionset".  Today, after 4 weeks, I find my own solution, AFTER playing the dvds in Mac and Win7 and then browsing Filehippo for clues. QUICKTIME ! We need to install the quicktime lib and util, in addition to all the restricteds, libs, etc advised in the Ubuntu forum. Use Synaptic for this. This solved the problem why commercial dvd in China would not play. ps... if you get an error message about "blocks", your drive may be faulty.