# Ubuntu 12.04: why could it not read DVD? (Encryption)

Tags: 12.04, encryption, vlc, dvd, commercial

How to play commercial DVDs on lenovo t-500 laptop?
I have Ubuntu 12.04, all updates

[Could not read dvd despite having restricted extras](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136189/could-not-read-dvd-despite-having-restricted-extras)

I tried the following, but VLC does not play DVDs.

```
 sudo apt-get install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly

 sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: @Mitch he has already tried the solutions described there.

Comment: However did you reboot after doing that?

Comment: Rebooting shouldn't be necessary (It wasn't for me, at least.) Please post the exact error message so we know what's specifically going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

Followed by

```
sudo apt-get install w32codecs
```

If you are on 64 bit install w64codecs instead however.

Answer (score 0):

Open VLC Player. Press on Ctrl+D (or choose Media --> Open DISC). From there choose your Media type then click on Play. [See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9zRc.jpg)

Comment: I set the regioncode to 2 (europe) (sudo regionset) I pressed Ctrl D, opened in VLC the window where to choose the media, and chose "no disc menus" and now VLC plays partially the DVD. The sound comes later and the screen is all the time green. @Hejar Mukriyani